# Use different locale for the Format function?

Tags: vb6

In a VB6 application I have to build a file which contains a decimal number which must *always* be written in US format:

```
1,499.99
```

But the `Format` function takes the system settings into account and on a German system this result would be produced: (Using the format string `#,##0.00`)

```
1.499,99
```

Can I force the `Format` function to use different settings?

Answer (score 2):

`Str()` will always use dot as decimal delimiter, however it won't use any digit separator. You would get " 1499.99" not "1,499.99". How's that for you?

As far as I know there is no way to force the VB6 `Format()` function to ignore system settings.

Comment: It's doable by hooking `GetLocaleInfo` which is ugly. That's why I'm not proposing it as a solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

try using SetThreadLocale before FormatMessage

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374051(VS.85).aspx

Comment: sorry, I misread the Q, I thought the user was using FormatMessage.  still, if format is really getting the system local info at time of execute, then SetThreadLocale should work.  maybe VB6 is querying the locale info at app start up, and therefore SetThreadLocale may not help.

Comment: Actually it's OLE dlls that are caching these values from `GetLocaleInfo`